# Android: How would you make Buttons un-clickable for some period?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I've got some Buttons that I want to make un-clickable (but still appear on the screen) until another process (thread) has finished its work ? How would you do this ?

The goal is to avoid my users to keep clicking on this button and so, launching a new thread every time they click on it ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a Button gray and unclickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019857/how-to-set-a-button-gray-and-unclickable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Don't use Threads unless you **really** have to. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.
2. Use [`setEnabled`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)) on your `Button` in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`.