# How to set a Button gray and unclickable?

Tags: android

I want to set the button unclickable and look like a dark gray image of an button?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

From the xml:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

From the code

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Note that this will only disable the button, not turn it gray like the original question asked.

Answer (score 4):

What about button.setEnabled(false) ?

Answer (score 4):

simply set the attribute android:enabled="false" in your xml.